# OpenLdap 2.4 ACL

Tags: acl, bind, openldap

can you help me with rights for group `OpenLdap 2.4`?

There is my `slapd.conf`

```
# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2

#Basic rights for authentication
access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none

#Rights for groups GR_READ and GR_WRITE
access to *
  by self write
  by group.exact="cn=GR_READ,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" read
  by group.exact="cn=GR_WRITE,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" write
  by * none
```

This configuration work fine. I have people in groups with name `GR_READ and GR_WRITE`

But my problem is with synchronize DIT between two Openldap DB. 
Synchronization do not work! I recieved error findbase failed! 32 in `slapd.log`
I have Multi-master configuration.

If I change configuration `slapd.conf` to this:

```
#Basic rights for authentication
access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none

#Rights for groups GR_READ and GR_WRITE
access to *
    by * read
```

Synchronization works! No errors in `slapd.log`. But I do not have a rights to my groups and anonymous user can bind LDAP.

Then I have another problem with disable anonymous.
If I change

```
# Allow LDAPv2 client connections.  This is NOT the default.
allow bind_v2
```

TO

```
disallow bind_anon
```

Synchronization do not work! I recieved error findbase failed! 32 in `slapd.log`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify bind information in the `syncrepl` statements and explicitly grant global read access to these entities preferably via another group `REPLICAS`.

Also I'd recommend to refactor your ACL like this:

```
access to *
  by group.exact="cn=REPLICAS,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" read
  by self write
  by group.exact="cn=GR_WRITE,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" write
  by group.exact="cn=GR_READ,ou=groups,ou=BGA,o=Company,c=com" read
  by * none
```

Otherwise users which are members of `GR_WRITE` and `GR_READ` cannot write. Order is significant: Control flow stops at first match!

Furthermore, I'd review whether `by self write` is secure for all your use-cases. But that's your security policy...